# Authentication system confused

Tags: java

I'm doing a project where I'm creating an authentication program for employees to log in to at a zoo. Log in attempts are limited to 3. The usernames and passwords are stored in the credentials.txt file. If the login is correct the corresponding text file from the 4th column should show up. The hash will be converted with MD5 which was already provided, just had to paste into the code.

```
griffin.keyes       108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    "alphabet soup"     zookeeper
rosario.dawson      3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5    "animal doctor"     admin
bernie.gorilla      a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b    "secret password"   veterinarian
donald.monkey       17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3    "M0nk3y business"   zookeeper
jerome.grizzlybear  3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900    "grizzly1234"       veterinarian
bruce.grizzlybear   0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7    "letmein"           admin
```

The problem I'm having is when I use a correct username and password, it still shows as wrong name and password. I can't figure out if I inserted MD4 message digest in wrong or if something else is wrong. I don't have much experience with this but hears my code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AuthenticationSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        Scanner scnr;
        scnr = new Scanner(new File("/Users/milanpatel/NetBeansProjects/AuthenticationSystem/src/authenticationsystem/credentials.txt"));
        String credentials [][]= new String[100][4];
        int count = 0;

        while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = scnr.nextLine();

            credentials[count][0] = line.substring(0, 20).trim();
            credentials[count][1] = line.substring(20, 55).trim();
            credentials[count][2] = line.substring(55, 74).trim();
            credentials[1][3] = line.substring(74).trim();
            count++;
         }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean run = true;
        int tries = 0;

        while (run) {
            System.out.println("-Welcome-");
            System.out.println("1-Login");
            System.out.println("2-Exit");

            int ch = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());

            if (ch == 1) {
//increment number of attempts
                tries++;
//request username and password
                System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
                String username = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
                String password = input.nextLine();
//generate hash
                String original = "letmein";  //Replace "password" with the actual password inputted by the user
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md.update(original.getBytes());
                byte[] digest = md.digest();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : digest) {
                    sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
                }
                String hPassword = sb.toString();

                boolean badUser = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    if (username.contentEquals(credentials[i][0])) {
                        if (hPassword.contentEquals(credentials[i][1])) {
//if verified, logged in
                            List<String> data = null;
//check type of user and print
                            switch (credentials[i][3]) {
                                case "zookeeper":
                                   data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("zookeeper.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                    break;
                                case "admin":
                                    data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("admin.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                    break;
                                case "veterinarian":
                                    data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("veterinarian.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            if (data != null) {
                                for (String s : data) {
                                    System.out.println(s);
                                }
                            }
//reset
                            tries = 0;

                            System.out.println("\n1) Logout.");
                            System.out.println("2) Exit.");

                            ch = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());
                            if (ch == 2) {
                                run = false;
                            }
                            badUser = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (badUser) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Username or password.");
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
//limit attempts
            if (tries == 3) {
                run = false;
                System.out.println("You have exceeded the number of login attempts.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with debugging in your IDE. What are these two lines supposed to do? `int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {`

Comment: Try to follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names (like `RUN`) should start with a lowercase letter. Also, avoid unnecessary nesting like `if (username.contentEquals(credentials[i][0])) { if (hPassword.contentEquals(credentials[i][1])) { ... }}` — you can combine these two with a compound condition: `if (username.contentEquals(credentials[i][0] && hPassword.contentEquals(credentials[i][1]) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `credentials` matrix, you only have the last read credentials because you are always overwrite the already entered credentials, without going forward in your matrix.

Move the

```
int count = 0;
```

from inside your while loop (where yo do the `scnr.hasNextLine()`) outside. 
You will have a compilation error because you already have defined a `int count = 0;`, so either remove the redefine and just reset the count or define a different variable so you don't accidentally misuse it.

As Erwin Bolwidt said in the comment, you will need to debug your application in your local IDE, beucase this was the first problem that I saw, there might be more problems.

**UPDATE**:
On the second run, I noticed that you are using the `count` for the loop that you are doing to check if the user is a `badUser` or not.

Suggestion: leave the `int count = 0;` in the current name that it has and don't declare a second variable, just reuse the one that you previously created and use that when you do the loop. This means remove the second `int count = 0;` from this lines:

```
boolean badUser = true;
int count = 0;
```

and just leave

```
boolean badUser = true;
```

the `for` loop following (`for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {`) should work fine afterwards.

I don't have all the information about your program, but I went ahead and succesfully "logged in", besides the part where you read the `.txt` file associated with my "role"

**UPDATE 2**: change this line from:

```
credentials[1][3] = line.substring(74).trim();
```

to

```
credentials[count][3] = line.substring(74).trim();
```

You other issue is related to the fact that you are creating the md5 password always against the `original` variable instead of what the use has entered:

change these lines from:

```
String password = input.nextLine();
//generate hash
String original = "letmein";  //Replace "password" with the actual password inputted by the user
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(original.getBytes());
```

to this:

```
String password = input.nextLine();
//generate hash
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(password.getBytes());
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

Here is the entire program:

```
public class AuthenticationSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        Scanner scnr;
        scnr = new Scanner(new File("/Users/milanpatel/NetBeansProjects/AuthenticationSystem/src/authenticationsystem/credentials.txt"));
        String credentials[][] = new String[100][4];
        int count = 0;

        while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = scnr.nextLine();

            credentials[count][0] = line.substring(0, 20).trim();
            credentials[count][1] = line.substring(20, 55).trim();
            credentials[count][2] = line.substring(55, 74).trim();
            credentials[count][3] = line.substring(74).trim();
            count++;
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean run = true;
        int tries = 0;

        while (run) {
            System.out.println("-Welcome-");
            System.out.println("1-Login");
            System.out.println("2-Exit");

            int ch = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());

            if (ch == 1) {
//increment number of attempts
                tries++;
//request username and password
                System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
                String username = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
                String password = input.nextLine();
//generate hash
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md.update(password.getBytes());
                byte[] digest = md.digest();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : digest) {
                    sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
                }
                String hPassword = sb.toString();

                boolean badUser = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    if (username.contentEquals(credentials[i][0])) {
                        if (hPassword.contentEquals(credentials[i][1])) {
//if verified, logged in
                            List<String> data = null;
//check type of user and print
                            switch (credentials[i][3]) {
                                case "zookeeper":
                                    data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("zookeeper.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                    break;
                                case "admin":
                                    data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("admin.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                    break;
                                case "veterinarian":
                                    data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("veterinarian.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            if (data != null) {
                                for (String s : data) {
                                    System.out.println(s);
                                }
                            }
//reset
                            tries = 0;

                            System.out.println("\n1) Logout.");
                            System.out.println("2) Exit.");

                            ch = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());
                            if (ch == 2) {
                                run = false;
                            }
                            badUser = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (badUser) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Username or password.");
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
//limit attempts
            if (tries == 3) {
                run = false;
                System.out.println("You have exceeded the number of login attempts.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I took it out of the while loop and defined a different variable. I changed my code above to show that. I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: I did it and nothing changed, I'm very confused. any other ideas?

Comment: @m.pat check my update 2 section. But please try to learn how to debug your program.

Comment: It still didn't work but thank you. I asked my professor for some input. I'm trying to learn, this is all still new to me.

Comment: I figured out how to debug line by line and it's showing some issue here    if (hPassword.contentEquals(credentials[i][1])) {

Comment: `showing some issue` is it pretty generic statement. You need to provide the error or exception stacktrace if you bump into some issue. I cannot know what is the issue, since I mentioned that for me it worked fine, so you need to help me out